# Accessing Workflow History List

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow

Is there an easy way to access History list, than to type URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Site Settings to add a QuickLaunch Url (use /_layouts/quiklnch.aspx) to lead to your workflow history list.